# How to use standard tokenizer with preserve_original?

Tags: elasticsearch

I created 2 custom analyzers as shown below but both doesnt work as I wanted. 
here is what i want in my inverted index 
for example; for the word `reb-tn2000xxxl` i need to have
reb, tn2000xxl, reb-tn2000xxxl in my inverted index.

```
{  
   "analysis":{  
      "filter":{  
         "my_word_delimiter":{  
            "split_on_numerics":"true",
            "generate_word_parts":"true",
            "preserve_original":"true",
            "generate_number_parts":"true",
            "catenate_all":"true",
            "split_on_case_change":"true",
            "type":"word_delimiter"
         }
      },
      "analyzer":{  
         "my_analyzer":{  
            "filter":[  
               "standard",
               "lowercase",
               "my_word_delimiter"
            ],
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"whitespace"
         },
         "standard_caseinsensitive":{  
            "filter":[  
               "standard",
               "lowercase"
            ],
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"keyword"
         },
         "my_delimiter":{  
            "filter":[  
               "lowercase",
               "my_word_delimiter"
            ],
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"standard"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

if I use `my_analyzer` which implements `whitespace` tokenizer, results looks like below if i check with curl

```
  curl -XGET "index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty=true" -d "reb-tn2000xxxl"
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "reb-tn2000xxxl",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "reb",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "rebtn2000xxxl",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "tn",
    "start_offset" : 4,
    "end_offset" : 6,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "2000",
    "start_offset" : 6,
    "end_offset" : 10,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "xxxl",
    "start_offset" : 10,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 3
  } ]
}
```

so here I am missing `tn2000xxxl`split which can be obtained if I use `standard` tokenizer instead of `whitespace` but problem is once I use standard like  `my_delimiter` custom analyzer is using. I dont have original value in the inverted index. It seems that `standard` tokinezer and `preserve_original` filter together doesnt work. I read somewhere that because standard tokenizer already splits on original before filter is applied, that's why original is no longer is the same. but How can I achieve this task to prevent original while splitting like standard tokenizer?

```
curl -XGET "index/_analyze?analyzer=my_delimiter&pretty=true" -d "reb-tn2000xxxl"
{  
   "tokens":[  
      {  
         "token":"reb",
         "start_offset":0,
         "end_offset":3,
         "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
         "position":0
      },
      {  
         "token":"tn2000xxxl",
         "start_offset":4,
         "end_offset":14,
         "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
         "position":1
      },
      {  
         "token":"tn",
         "start_offset":4,
         "end_offset":6,
         "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
         "position":1
      },
      {  
         "token":"tn2000xxxl",
         "start_offset":4,
         "end_offset":14,
         "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
         "position":1
      },
      {  
         "token":"2000",
         "start_offset":6,
         "end_offset":10,
         "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
         "position":2
      },
      {  
         "token":"xxxl",
         "start_offset":10,
         "end_offset":14,
         "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
         "position":3
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Elasticsearch, you can have multi-fields on your mapping. The behavior that you are describing is actually pretty common. You can have your main `text` field analyzed with the `standard` analyzer and a `keyword` field as well. Here's an example mapping using multi-fields from the documentation. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

> ```
> PUT my_index
> {
>   "mappings": {
>     "_doc": {
>       "properties": {
>         "city": {
>           "type": "text",
>           "fields": {
>             "raw": { 
>               "type":  "keyword"
>             }
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

In this example, the `"city"` field will be analyzed with the `standard` analyzer and `"city.raw"` will be the non-analyzed `keyword`. In other words, `"city.raw"` is the original string.

Comment: so you cant have without having 2nd field? because query time, you have to query both combine result with some should and "and" operator i believe which may bring different results

Comment: You can query both fields at the same time. You can use a `multi_match` or `query_string` or a `bool` query with multiple `must` or `should` clauses. Lots of options in the [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html).

Comment: is that raw a keyword? or you can use any other word? because when I use something else, ES indexer returns error for me. I mean if i need even 3rd version of a field, can i call .raw2?

Comment: `"city.raw"` is of the type `keyword` but it can be named whatever you want. If you need help with your mapping, feel free to post another question or look through the multi-field documentation again. Sometimes it takes reading it 3 or 4 times. :)